# How to enable Oauth2 login in Outlook (Desktop or App) for own Postfix/Dovecot mail server

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, imap, email-client, dovecot

We have our own mailserver with Postfix/Dovecot and have activated the SASL oauth plugins for that. The question that we can not seem to find the answer to is the following: We now want people to be able to add that email account to, lets say Outlook Desktop or Mobile App, which both support Oauth2, for example shown if you add an gmail.com address. However, how does this work for another email provider/your own server? There is no documentation to be found anywhere, but some sites, like this one (https://searchfox.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/src/OAuth2Providers.jsm), suggest that clients hard code oAuth endpoints, so making oAuth2 impossible for anyone else then a few global players?
Hopefully clients like Outlook do that differently, but how? It can not be that every client has to hardcode any potential oauth server, right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

That’s unfortunately correct.  Using Oauth is fairly standardized, but issuing OAuth is basically custom for each provider. The whole point is that there has to be a cooperation and vetting between the provider and the client (handled during registration, issuing of scopes, setting of endpoints, etc.)  Therefore, there’s no way to automatically add support to a client.

Comment: Wow, that would mean that oAuth would never work for Outlook except if you are able to convince Microsoft to hard code your solution's endpoint??

Comment: The OAuth provider usually would issue a client identifier and scope names, and the endpoints.  The developer the needs to add that to their app.  Now maybe it's possible some apps have configuration for that (like, web browsers can have corporate proxy settings applied automatically), but it's not really common.  OAuth really is just a fancy way to automate and and decentralize app passwords.  For smaller outfits, app passwords are really the way to go.  I don't know if postfix or whatever-software has support, but app passwords would get you the same security for the most part.